# How to use a RaspberryPi camera with the cv2.videoCapture() function?

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, libcamera

I am building a face-id detection program on my raspberry pi, for which I need to use OpenCV along with my RaspberryPi camera. However, when I run my code, I keep on getting an error which I am guessing is because the cv2.VideoCapture() function is not able to take input from my RaspberryPi camera.

Whenever I run the following code, I get the following error:
**Code**

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("/dev/video12")
print(cap)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    
    cv2.imshow("frame", frame)
    
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**Error**

```
[ WARN:0@0.572] global ./modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (1127) open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Error opening bin: no element "dev"
[ WARN:0@0.572] global ./modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (862) isPipelinePlaying OpenCV | GStreamer warning: GStreamer: pipeline have not been created
< cv2.VideoCapture 0x7f80b53750>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/test.py", line 9, in <module>
    cv2.imshow("frame", frame)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) ./modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:967: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'imshow'
```

Whenever I use 0 instead of "dev/video12," I get a black window without the

```
live feed. I also get this warning:
[ WARN:0@0.759] global ./modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (1405) open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Cannot query video position: status=0, value=-1, duration=-1
< cv2.VideoCapture 0x7f91381bb0>
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 148 (Unknown), sequence: 191, resource id: 0, major code: 140 (Unknown), minor code: 20
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
```

I am guessing this has something to do with the cv2.VideoCapture() function not taking input from my camera. I am using a RaspberryPi 3B with Bookworm. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that it is `dev/video12` and not `/dev/video12`?

Comment: Still the same error. Should I be using a different number than "12"?

Comment: Sure, you can try. But first check in your console with `ls /dev/vid*` if something like this exists and what other videos there are.

Comment: There are many, but all of them end up giving the same error. If put 0, like you would with a normal web cam, then a window does pop up, but it doesn't show the live feed from the camera and I'm still greeted with some warnings.

Comment: answer is simple: you don't. you use libcamera2 instead. opencv does not support this strange library. OpenCV supports standard ***video for linux (V4L)*** APIs however, but those pi cams don't support that.